# Replacing vintage bike tyres

Tags: tire, vintage, advice, peugeot

I have a 1980 Peugeot road bike and the tyres need replacing.

The existing tyres say:
700 x 25c
25-622

Which I thought was pretty standard?

Someone in the Decathlon bike shop told me this was niche and I would struggle replacing them. He said my options were to hunt for vintage parts or go all in and get new wheels.

Is that right? I'd obviously prefer to just get new tyres if I can!

I'd really appreciate any advice!

Comment: They sound like pretty normal-sized modern tires to me. Searching the net for "700x25c tires" gives many options to buy. 25-622 is a modern ETRTO sizing nomenclature, meaning your existing tires are not that old.

Comment: 'Decathlon bike shop told me this was niche and I would struggle replacing them', - Seriously! All the while you were probably a few meters away from a whole rack of 25-622 tires !

Comment: Yeh, but the profit in  arack of tires is less than a new wheel set. Bet he was pointing the OP to the lightest carbon wheels he could find in the catelogue.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - I won't be going to Decathlon again!

Answer (score 9):

No, that person was confused and you have it right. A new 700x25 tire will fit the same as what you have. Often 40 year old wheels will need new rim strips while you're at it.

Comment: Thank you! So glad I asked, I thought I was right

Comment: And new inner tubes as well. And while you're at it and you have some money left, get a decent track pump, if you don't already have one. It's something you won't regret.